# VS2012: “Cannot find the resource compiler DLL. Please make sure the path is correct.”

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll, mfc

When I try to open a resource view of a VC++ 2012 project (MFC) for resource editing, I get this error:  “Cannot find the resource compiler DLL. Please make sure the path is correct.”

I did find an earlier question on SO: "VS2010: “Cannot find the resource compiler DLL. Please make sure the path is correct.” and many other similar through Google, but none of the advise given there helps. Did twice the repair of my VS2012 setup, did try all the registry tweaks mentioned in the articles. It appears that the DLL needed is rcdll.dll, found it in several Windows SDK Bin directories, added them to the system path (both 32-bit and x64 directory), and still nothing.

Wasted over 4 hours on this issue. Is there anything else to try? Thanks!

Greg

Comment: please post your code, and show us where it's failing so we can help

Comment: Philip, code is irrelevant, it fails to open any resource editing part of any VC++ project... The part where you edit dialog boxes, menus, toolbars in VS.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason SO logged me under a different account when I posted the above question. Won't approve my own answer to avoid giving points to myself.

Finally figured it out, after an hour or so tracing all the file and registry access calls VS2012 devenv.exe makes, using Sysinternals procmon. Turns out that VS2012, at least on my system, was looking only for this key, ignoring everything else:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0
```

Once I set the **InstallationFolder** value there to a valid Windows SDK folder (no matter if it was version 7, 7.1 or 8.1 SDK), all started working normally. What's strange is that all other posts on similar problems were suggesting to set:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows
```

value of *CurrentInstallFolder* and *CurrentVersion* to whichever SDK you wanted it to use, and it was supposed to work. Not so, only the above mentioned key and value was read and respected. Reinstalling Windows 7.1 and 8.1 SDKs several times was not helping either.

Maybe it's some kind of bug in VS2012 Update 4, the most current at the time of this writing. So many hours lost on a stupid issue like this, hope this writeup helps someone else to avoid such loss.

Greg

Answer (score 0):

you can just simply change the compiler from resource compiler to C / C++ Compiler and you can do that by simply making a resource and you will face that error after that right click the empty resource that have been generated and on the folder of resources right click the [nameofyourproject].rc and then choose properties and from item type change it to C / C++ Compiler.